# How to Log out from Facebook or revoke login using Parse and Swift

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk, logout

I'm trying to completely log my user out of my app. When using

```
PFUser.logout()
```

I successfully log the user out of Parse.
But when I come back in the app and click on the login button, I'm redirected to the Facebook screen saying :"You have already authorized [name of the app]"
So I can never login again with another account, except if I reset the simulator.

I also tried to logout using

```
PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager().logOut()
```

But it doesn't work either...
Hope you can help me find a solution to this !
I'm using the latest Facebook and Parse SDK

**Update:**

Actually using `PFUser.logout()` and the last versions of **Parse** and the **Facebook iOS SDK version >= 4.4.0** will do the job.

Do not use `PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager().logOut()` or `FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()`, because it will only log the user out from **Facebook** but not from the **Parse** back-end. Which means that it will not delete the revocable session on the **Parse** back-end.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually there is a difference between **Revoking Login** (letting people completely de-authorizing an app, or revoking login) and **Logging out** an user from his/her Facebook account:

**Revoking Login**

(you can check the [Facebook documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.4))

You can also let people completely de-authorize an app, or revoke login, by making a call to this Graph API endpoint:

```
DELETE /{user-id}/permissions
```

This request must be made with a valid user access token or an app access token for the current app. If the request is successful, your app receives a response of true. If the call is successful, any user access token for the person will be invalidated and they will have to log in again. Because you're de-authorizing your app, they will also have to grant access to your app as if they were logging in for the first time.

```
let facebookRequest: FBSDKGraphRequest! = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/permissions", parameters: nil, HTTPMethod: "DELETE")

facebookRequest.startWithCompletionHandler { (connection: FBSDKGraphRequestConnection!, result: AnyObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in

                if(error == nil && result != nil){
                    println("Permission successfully revoked. This app will no longer post to Facebook on your behalf.")
                    println("result = \(result)")
                } else {
                    if let error: NSError = error {
                        if let errorString = error.userInfo?["error"] as? String {
                            println("errorString variable equals: \(errorString)")
                        }
                    } else {
                        println("No value for error key")
                    }
                }
}
```

**Logging out an user form his/her Facebook account**

If you have used **Parse** and the **Facebook iOS SDK version >= 4.4.0** to sign up or log in a user via **Facebook**, and you do not want to de-authorize an app, or revoke login, but just want to log out the user from Facebook, then please use instead:

```
PFUser.logOut()
```

It will log out the user, delete the session on the **Parse** back-end side (do not forget to [enable](http://blog.parse.com/announcements/announcing-new-enhanced-sessions/) Parse [revocable session](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#sessions-handling-invalid-session-token-error) via your Parse app settings), plus it will also delete the **Facebook** session written on the user device's disk.

I hope this answer will help you guys.

Comment: Thanks, the answer couldn't be clearer ! I knew I was missing something. It wasn't really a problem as we usually don't want to completely log the user out when he quits the app. At least now I know how to do this properly. Thanks again !

Comment: Do not forget to put a +1 to the question and the answer if it helped you guys.

Comment: doesn't work for me unfortunately. I always see "You have already authorized" screen no matter what I do

Comment: Still works. Excellent answer. Just make sure you do any logging out even in the success part to prevent any error. If you try to delete *after* logging out it will throw and error and you will not delete permissions.

Answer (score 1):

I just implemented this. Call this function from any viewController in the application and it will logout from facebook. Worked like a charm for me. I hope it helps you.

```
-(void) logout
{
    FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];

    if ( [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] ){
        [login logOut];
    }
}
```

Comment: This works with the current latest SDK of facebook not with any previos one.

Comment: Sure, and mark it as the correct answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Actually using `PFUser.logout()` and the last versions of **Parse** and the **Facebook iOS SDK version >= 4.4.0** will do the job.

Do not use `PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager().logOut()` or `FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()`, because it will only log the user out from **Facebook** but not from the **Parse** back-end. Which means that it will not delete the revocable session on the **Parse** back-end.

Answer (score -1):

Source: [Logout from facebook in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17880993/logout-from-facebook-in-ios-app)

```
- (void)logout:(id<FBSessionDelegate>)delegate {

  _sessionDelegate = delegate;

  NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
  [self requestWithMethodName:@"auth.expireSession"
                    andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"GET"
                  andDelegate:nil];

  [params release];
  [_accessToken release];
  _accessToken = nil;
  [_expirationDate release];
  _expirationDate = nil;

  NSHTTPCookieStorage* cookies = [NSHTTPCookieStorage sharedHTTPCookieStorage];
  NSArray* facebookCookies = [cookies cookiesForURL:
    [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://m.facebook.com"]];

  for (NSHTTPCookie* cookie in facebookCookies) {
    [cookies deleteCookie:cookie];
  }

  if ([self.sessionDelegate respondsToSelector:@selector(fbDidLogout)]) {
    [_sessionDelegate fbDidLogout];
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! But FBSessions don't exist anymore in the latest SDK so I can't use them...

Comment: @Simon is there any way you discovered to logout with the new facebook SDK ? I am stuck in the same problem.

Comment: Hi @AhsanEbrahim ! Unfortunately I didn't find a way to do this properly... For the moment I just use `PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager().logOut()` and `PFUser.logout()`
In the end it's not really a problem as a phone generally has only one user. But if you ever find a solution it would be great if you could notify me :)

Comment: @Simon see my answer i just posted. hope it helps you :)

Comment: **Update:**

Actually using `PFUser.logout()` and the last versions of **Parse** and the **Facebook iOS SDK version >= 4.4.0** will do the job.

Do not use `PFFacebookUtils.facebookLoginManager().logOut()` or `FBSDKLoginManager().logOut()`, because it will only log the user out from **Facebook** but not from the **Parse** back-end. Which means that it will not delete the revocable session on the **Parse** back-end.