# Failed logout parse.com user from Facebook

Tags: ios, parse-platform, facebook-ios-sdk

I login to Facebook in my game using

```
PFFacebookUtils logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions:@[@"email"]
    block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error)
```

But when I try to logout, and then login with some different user, I get the Facebook screen saying: "You have already authorized [name of the app]».

This message doesn’t disappear even I reinstall the application.
I have tried to logout different ways with these results:

1. No result, appear «You have already authorized».

   ```
   FBSDKLoginManager *login = [[FBSDKLoginManager alloc] init];
   if ( [FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] ){
       [login logOut];
       NSLog(@"The user is no longer associated with their Facebook account.");
   }
   ```
2. Can’t run application, because there is no sessions in Facebook SDK v.4.

   ```
   [PFFacebookUtils.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];
   [PFUser logOut];
   ```
3. No result, appear «You have already authorized».

   ```
   [PFFacebookUtils unlinkUserInBackground:[PFUser currentUser] 
       block:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
       if (succeeded) {
           NSLog(@"The user is no longer associated with their Facebook account.");
       }
       else{
           NSLog(@"Failure logout FB: %@", error);
       }
   }];
   [PFUser logOut];
   ```

Also I get an error in logs:

`[Error]: username xxxx already taken (Code: 202, Version: 1.9.1).`

I saw this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30716200/how-to-log-out-from-facebook-or-revoke-login-using-parse-and-swift). It says, problem was solved in Facebook SDK version >= 4.4. But I use Parse SDK v.1.9.1 and Facebook SDK v.4.7, and get the same failure.
Can I doing something wrong?

**Update:**
Thanks [jbehrens94's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4444642/jbehrens94) response, this is right version:

```
[[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me/permissions"
                                   parameters:nil
                                   HTTPMethod:@"DELETE"]
 startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
     if (!error)
         NSLog(@"Revoking is successfull");
     else
         NSLog(@"Failure revoking: %@", error);
 }];
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because of Facebook's way of authenticating a user via OAuth. When someone logs into your app with Facebook, the app makes a request to Facebook to gain access to Facebook's data.
Facebook adds the app to the user's profile with certain access, so the only way you'll be able to re-login with Facebook and not see that screen, is to remove the app manually from your Facebook settings.

The question/post you linked to describes this correctly, and I quote:

`Actually there is a difference between Revoking Login (letting people completely de-authorizing an app, or revoking login) and Logging out an user from his/her Facebook account`.

Comment: Thanks for response! Do you know, Twitter uses the same method?

Comment: Twitter uses the same method, yeah. :)